# Where can I see who is currently logged in to Plone?

Tags: plone, zope

Is there a way to see who is currently logged in to a Plone site?

Rationale: I want to make sure not to interfer with users working on content when I restart the instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Out-of-the-box, there is no way to see if users are currently using your site, only if they have just been using it. Just tail the `instance-Z2.log` access logfile.

Note that due to the nature of the HTTP protocol, 'current' users of your site do not maintain a connection, and thus, until they are back again for the next request, there is no accurate way to determine if anyone is using the site.

There are work-arounds, such as using sessions and timeouts, that use recency to estimate how many users are still around. `collective.portlet.usertrack` is one such approach. Note that such approaches can have a hefty scalability penalty though.

If all you want to do is not inconvenience users during a restart, use a caching frontend and / or a load balancer and more than one instance instead. That way users see cached content or content generated by an instance still up while you restart your first instance.

Answer (score 2):

you can try [collective.portlet.usertrack](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.portlet.usertrack)